# Updating a table in my trigger fails

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a table using an `after insert` trigger using this code

```
SET @OLDTMP_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `le_log_trigger` AFTER INSERT ON `messagelog` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
declare last_inserted_number VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '0800100200';
declare last_inserted_code VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'Lorem Ipsum';
declare current_dataset VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'Lorem Ipsum';

set last_inserted_number = NEW.messagefrom;
set last_inserted_code = NEW.statuscode;
set current_dataset = (select task_name from running_tasks limit 1);

if(last_inserted_code = 201) then

update current_dataset set the_status = 'online' where device_number = last_inserted_number;

end if;

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

My database is called `logan` and i get this error when the trigger runs

```
/* SQL Error (1146): Table 'logan.current_dataset' doesn't exist */
```

Why is `current_dataset` not being treated as a variable?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're trying to do an `UPDATE` query. MySQL expects to see a table name where you've got your variable, so it won't go "oh, hey, this was declared as a variable earlier". It'll just assume right away that it's supposed to be a literal table name, and look for that table... and since it can't be found (because it doesn't exist), you get that error.

If you DID by chance have a table where a field name did co-incide with a variable name, eg.

```
table x (foo int, bar int);
set bar='baz';
```

and did

```
UPDATE x SET foo=bar
```

then you've got a problem. Which `bar` should be used? Are you referring the variable, or to the field? That's why there's `@`:

```
UPDATE x SET foo=bar ; // use "bar" field in the table
UPDATE x SET foo=@bar; // use variable "bar" value.
```

And note that you couldn't use the variable as a table name, e.g.

```
SET x = 'tablename';
UPDATE @x SET ...
```

is just a flat-out syntax error. You'd have to build a query string inside your sproc, and then prepare/execute it.

Comment: I am shocked this `SET x = 'tablename';
UPDATE @x SET ...` would always result into an error. How should i get around this error?.

Comment: if you just want to change the value of your `current_dataset` variable, then just use another `set`, e.g. `set @foo=@foo+1` is entirely legal.

Comment: +1. I concur with with what Marc B says here, with one minor quibble; the "reason why there's @". (When there's a collision between a procedure variable and an column name, that's not necessarily a problem. MySQL has defined behavior, the column name takes precedence; and that's different than other databases.) MySQL user-defined variables (`@var`) are MUCH different than procedure variables (`DECLARE var`), and that difference, and the reason for  user-defined variables, goes way beyond resolving collisions within stored programs.